# Is there a way to create a shortcut in IntelliJ for multiple consecutive actions?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a single shortcut in IntelliJ that does multiple consecutive actions.

For example, the following actions are needed to deploy a service:

- check out the master branch
- pull changes
- check out the production branch
- pull changes
- merge the master branch into the production branch
- push changes

Each of these actions can be done with a shortcut (and a bit of typing/selection in the case of the checking out), but I would like to do all of these in this order with a single shortcut.

Comment: see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html

Comment: Nice, the only issue I ran into is pressing ENTER too fast before the branch is actually ready. Is it possible to wait for an action to complete or for a certain period of time in a macro?